# Making selectable again a WPF TreeviewITem after the first click

Tags: asp.net, .net, wpf

I have a TreeView WPF with 2 Levels of Data.
I have deleted the ToogleButton from the TreeViewItemTemplate. Now I'd like to expand / collapse the groups with a single mouse-click (not with a double click as the default behaviour).
I have tried in this way:

```
Private Sub tvArt_SelectedItemChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, _
    ByVal e As RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs(Of System.Object)) Handles tvArt.SelectedItemChanged

    If e.NewValue Is Nothing = False Then
        Dim ri As P_RicambiItem = TryCast(e.NewValue, P_RicambiItem)
        If ri Is Nothing = False Then
            If ri.isExpanded Then
                ri.isExpanded = False
            Else
                ri.isExpanded = True
            End If
            ri.isSelected = False
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Using my properties `isExpanded` and `isSelected` in the collection data source.

But it works only halfway:  after the first click, infact, I can't click for a second time on the same item, because, even if I've deselected it, the event handler "remembers" that it was the last selected item and it doesn't capture the event `SelectedItemChanged`.

How can I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easiest way is probably to handle the PreviewMouseDown event on the TreeView and identify when the mouse clicks the parent TreeViewItems:

XAML:

```
<TreeView Name="treeView1" TreeView.PreviewMouseDown="OnTreeViewPreviewMouseDown" />
```

Code-behind:

```
private void OnTreeViewPreviewMouseDown( object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e )
{
    TreeViewItem tvi = GetTreeViewItemClicked( (FrameworkElement) e.OriginalSource, treeView1 );
    if ( null == tvi ) return;
    tvi.IsExpanded = !tvi.IsExpanded;
}

private static TreeViewItem GetTreeViewItemClicked( UIElement sender, UIElement treeView )
{
    Point p = sender.TranslatePoint( new Point( 0, 0 ), treeView );
    var obj = treeView.InputHitTest( p ) as DependencyObject;
    while ( obj != null && !( obj is TreeViewItem ) )
    {
        obj = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent( obj );
    }
    return obj as TreeViewItem;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! But I can't find the "Click" event for the TreeView. In the "MouseUp" event I can't see the data because the treeviewitem is still not selected. Can you, please, show me a little snippet of code? C# is good, I'll do the "translation".

Comment: Yeah, sorry. That was a little misleading. I updated the approach to handle the PreviewMouseDown event instead.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you very much! It works very well, if someone should be interested, this is my Vb version:

```
Private Sub tvArt_PreviewMouseDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As MouseButtonEventArgs) Handles tvArt.PreviewMouseDown
    Dim tvi As TreeViewItem = GetTreeViewItemClicked(e.OriginalSource, Me.tvArt)
    If tvi Is Nothing = False Then
        If tvi.HasItems Then
            tvi.isExpanded = Not tvi.isExpanded
        End If
    End If
End Sub

Private Function GetTreeViewItemClicked(ByVal sender As UIElement, ByVal _treeView As UIElement) As TreeViewItem
    Dim p As Point = sender.TranslatePoint(New Point(0, 0), _treeView)
    Dim obj As DependencyObject = DirectCast(_treeView.InputHitTest(p), DependencyObject)
    While obj Is Nothing = False AndAlso TypeOf obj Is TreeViewItem = False
        obj = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(obj)
    End While
    Return DirectCast(obj, TreeViewItem)
End Function
```